# "Object library not registered", recovering from failed hard drive on win 10

Tags: windows, vb6, registration

After SSD failure, reinstalled Win10 and vb6. Application uses Far Point 2.5 spread sheet component, ss32x25.ocx. regsrv32 loads but call to DllRegisterServer fails w/code 0x80040201. Project Components display from IDE shows Far Point 2.5 in use, but project.vdp does not contain object reference "Object={B02F3647-766B-11CE-AF28-C3A2FBE76A13}#2.5#0; ss32x25.ocx".

When run in IDE, registry error above shows. Has also said "not registerable as an ActiveX Component".

Second machine, no failures, properly runs same app and displays objects being used. I have all support files for ss32x25.ocx.

Note that VB6 no longer installs cleanly due to Win10 changes; both machines have experienced that wild ride before ~ 3 years ago. This one looks just about ready to take off. Just need to fix registration.

Comment: Have you also reinstalled Farpoint? That should register all necessary components. If everything fails, contact the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong in my statement that object reference "Object={B02F3647-766B-11CE-AF28-C3A2FBE76A13}#2.5#0; ss32x25.ocx" was missing in the project.vbp file. It was 2 pages down the list.

This all started in re-loading visual studio. Somehow I learned loading only VB as admin were the keys to success. Reloading Far Point occurred somewhere in the process. But it wasn't a clean register for it or a home grown dll defining a batch of structures. regsvr32 loaded but failed some specific call.

Registration had to be the problem. I explored regedit and found Far Point looked good but my dll had gotten nowhere. Noting I still had to run the IDE as admin, I tried regsvr32 as admin for both items. Both were successful!

And, I don't have to run the IDE as admin!